# Foreach in a IList with Anonymous Type

Tags: c#

I have an `IList` and with `QuickWatch` I could see the following

```
Name                    Value                                 Type
ListStatusProposta      { Value = "1", Text = "Beginner" }    <Anonymous Type>
      Text              "Beginner"                            object{string}
      Value             "1"                                   object{string}
```

How can I do a `foreach` to access these properties ?

**Update**

This is how I fill my `IList`

```
protected static object[,] StatusProposta()
{
    object[,] status = {
    { "1", "Beginner" },
    { "2", "Intermediate" },
    { "3", "Advanced" }
                      };

    return status;
}


//public static IList fillLista(string nome)
public static IList<object> fillLista(string nome)
        {
            //List<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>();
            List<object> list = new List<object>();
            object[,] objeto;

            switch (nome) 
            {                
                case "StatusProposta":
                    objeto = StatusProposta();
                    break;
                default:
                    objeto = null;
                    break;
            }            

            if (objeto != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < (objeto.Length / 2); i++)
                    list.Add(new { Value = objeto[i, 0], Text = objeto[i, 1] });
            }

            return list;
        }



//IList ListaStatusProposta = fillLista("StatusProposta");
IList<object> ListaStatusProposta = fillLista("StatusProposta");
foreach()
{
// ????
}
```

Comment: This is not an "anonymous type". You are using an `object` array and `dynamic`.

Comment: Strage because when I take a look using QuickWatch, inform that this is an anonymous type. How could I do the foreach in this case ?

Comment: I mean the type returned by `StatusProposta` and the `list` type. However, you _are_ creating an anonymous type when adding the values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The anonymous type does have properties that can be accessed as normal:

```
foreach(var item in myList)
{
   var val = item.Value;
   var txt = item.Text;
}
```

---

One of the issues here is that the return type of `fillLista` is `IList` and not a *generic* `IList` this causes all values in the list to be cast to `object`.

Return `IList<dynamic>` instead.

Comment: I tryied this one, but return a error message in `Value` propertie: `'object' does not contains a definition for 'Value'`.

Comment: @Lucas_Santos - Are you casting to `object` anywhere? Note I am using `var`, not `object` in the `foreach`.

Comment: Deleted my answer because this was the same as mine (at the same time), and was updated based on the update to the original question.

Comment: I alter my code (updated my question), but I can't access these properties. When I put the `Text`and `Value` propertie, this is an `object` in this case ?

Comment: @Lucas_Santos - Again, you are casting the dynamic list to an `object` list and by so also casting _each_ anonymous type to `object`. One solution is to not use an anonymous type but create a class for your usage.